# GROUP BY with a condition on WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  Group     as [Grupo],
  COUNT(*)  as [Total]
FROM
  Table
WHERE
  Status NOT IN ('Closed', 'Cancelled', 'Resolved') AND
  DATEDIFF(day,Submit_Date,GETDATE()) > 30
GROUP BY
  Group,
  DATEDIFF(day,Submit_Date,GETDATE())
```

The objective is to get tickets with aging above 30 days. The output is:

```
Group       Total
Group A         4
Group A         1
Group A         2
Group A         2
Group B         1
Group B         1
```

What I'm hoping to see:

```
Group       Total
Group A         9
Group B         2
```

I might be missing something dumb here... Can someone help me with this one? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure why you have the `DATEDIFF` in the group by, you are only grouping by "Group"

Answer (score 1):

seems like you just need to group by "Group" only:

```
SELECT
  Group     as [Grupo],
  COUNT(*)  as [Total]
FROM
  Table
WHERE
  Status NOT IN ('Closed', 'Cancelled', 'Resolved') AND
  DATEDIFF(day,Submit_Date,GETDATE()) > 30
GROUP BY
  Group
```

Comment: Faster than a comet. Thanks. You nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the `GROUP BY`.  These keys define each row and apparently you want one row per `group`.

I would also suggest fixing the date logic:

```
SELECT [Group] as [Grupo], COUNT(*)  as [Total]
FROM  Table
WHERE Status NOT IN ('Closed', 'Cancelled', 'Resolved') AND
      Submit_Date < DATEADD(DAY, -30 CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY [Group];
```

Avoiding the function call on `Submit_Date` should help the optimizer produce the best execution plan.